# Run lynx -dump in background?

Tags: bash, background-process, lynx, job-control

I have a bash script `mystuff` containing a line like

```
lynx -dump http://example.com >tmpfile
```

and the script works fine, including this part, *except* when I run it non-interactively:

```
$ ./mystuff &
[1] 3712
$ jobs
[1]+ Stopped
```

The job is stopped. I find that lynx is the culprit. Even running this command directly from the bash prompt causes the job to be stopped immediately:

```
$ lynx -dump http://example.com >tmpfile &
[1] 1836
$ jobs
[1]+ Stopped
```

Why won't lynx run in the background? How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

I am using lynx because I don't want to have to parse the raw HTML. The difference between `wget` and `lynx -dump` is that lynx will render the HTML; it will hide all the tags, arrange text nicely, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lynx wants to talk to your terminal, but can't, so it does a SIGSTP (tty input) and waits for you to foreground the process.

As mgb said above: use wget. `wget -O tmpfile http://example.com` does the same thing as what you're doing with lynx above.

Comment: Is there a way to fake the tty, or redirect it? I know I can use -term=ansi (for instance) to force the terminal type.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you must use lynx? Are you trying to take advantage of the fact that lynx will render the page in a text mode? On my system `w3m -dump` works properly without causing a STOP signal.

Comment: I was not aware of w3m, thanks! I've checked and it looks like it will work. I appreciate the explanation and the workaround.

Comment: In my experience, `wget -O` and `lynx -dump` aren't equivalent.  wget retains the markup while lynx converts to text.  This might vary by platform / version so just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer you are lookign for but could you just use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) instead?

Answer (score 1):

On my system, your lynx command works as is. Try this and see what happens:

```
lynx -dump -term=xterm http://example.com >tmpfile &
```

Answer (score 0):

We had luck running lynx --source http_setting://whatever|bash.

Running as bash allowed the background process to bypass running with my personal credentials and no tty discrepancies.

Comment: Thanks, but this answer misses the point. `lynx -source` is the same as `wget`, it provides raw HTML and then you have to parse it. I was trying to leverage the HTML parser in lynx to get simplified, human-readable text.